# Indexing for loops in lists consisting of matrices

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

I am struggling with indexing correctly piece of code below. Perhaps the set up of my data is not ideal either.

First, I want to compare values between two columns in `abcd` `b` and `d`
and each set of generated `RandomNum` rows.
If the row value in `RandomNum` is greater than `b` `abcd` value, 
then it should = 0, if else it should = 1
The outcome would be a list with two matrices, one comparing column `b`
and one column or vector `d` against each set of row values (treated as vectors) in `RandomNum` using criteria described above. 
The outcome list would have 2 matrices with dimensions of `nv` * `rp` and would be saved as list `UDRandomNum`. 
Then, I want to take a difference between the outcome value 0 or 1 in `UDRandomNum` row or column of 3 and each time deduct it from columns `b` and `d` in `abcd`. So the outcome saved in `Differences` would again have two matrices, each one comparing set of vectors of three against the same column `b` and `d` from `abcd`. I hope it makes sense.

```
set.seed(101)
a <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
b <- c(0.8,0.2,0.5)
c <- c(0.4,0.9,1.0)
d <- c(0.7,0.9,0.2)
ab <- cbind(a,b)
cd <- cbind(c,d)
abcd <- list(ab,cd)

rp <- 100
nv <- length(a)

RandomNum <- vector("list",length(a))

# Draw random values between 0 and 1 from the uniform distribution
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
        RandomNum[[i]] <- t(replicate(rp, runif(nv, min=0,max=1)))
}
```

The problematic piece starts here:

```
UDRandomNum <- vector("list",length(abcd))

for (i in 1:length(abcd)) {
        UDRandomNum[[i]] <- RandomNum[[i]][i] < 
                abcd[[i]][,2][col(RandomNum[[i]])]+0
}

# Later, I want to take the difference between the outcomes (1 or 0)

Differences <- vector("list",length(abcd))

for (i in 1:length(abcd)) {
            Differences[[i]] <- abs(sweep(UDRandomNum,2,abcd[,2]))
}
```

So it my RandomNum I have the outcome that starts with:

```
[[1]]
              [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
  [1,] 0.076929106 0.42883794 0.502711454
  [2,] 0.254765247 0.57422550 0.578616861
  [3,] 0.270195792 0.30920944 0.094095268
  [4,] 0.512404975 0.97536980 0.082336057
  ...
```

I compare it with `b`: 0.8,0.2,0.5 (if the value in RandomNum is > b then we get 0, else we get 1)

`UDRandomNum:`

```
[[1]]
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  [1,] 1     0     0
  [2,] 1     0     0 
  [3,] 1     0     1 
  [4,] 1     0     1
  ...
```

And finally I would deduct values in UDRandomNum from `b` so the outcome in `Differences` would look following (whatever the results i typed equation for convenience, but it should be a number resulting from this equation)

```
  [[1]]
       [,1]               [,2]              [,3]
  [1,] abs(1-0.076929106) abs(0-0.42883794) abs(0-0.502711454)
  [2,] abs(1-0.254765247) abs(0-0.57422550) abs(0-0.578616861)
  [3,] abs(1-0.270195792) abs(0-0.30920944) abs(1-0.094095268)
  [4,] abs(1-0.512404975) abs(0-0.97536980) abs(1-0.082336057)
  ...
```

Comment: why is this exactly the same code as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267597/loops-involving-several-lists-in-r

Comment: Can you share an example of how you want to compare the columns b and d with RandomNum?

Comment: @so13eit : I did, hope it helps

Comment: Why is the `pa` column created?

Comment: @PierreLafortune : thanks for spotting, it was an artifact, it is removed now.

Comment: You are using it in your `UDRandomNum` for loop. Check this line, `newcolpa[[i]][,3]..` it is being repeated to compare to the `RandomNum` matrix. Should that be `[,2]` instead to refer to column `b` and `d`?

Comment: `RandomNum` and `UDRandomNum` are also made with different dimensions- `RandomNum` is of length 3 and `UDRandomNum` is of length 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UDRandomNum <- vector("list",length(abcd))

for (i in 1:length(abcd)) {
        UDRandomNum[[i]] <- RandomNum[[1]] < 
          matrix(abcd[[i]][,2][col(RandomNum[[i]])], ncol=3)
}

Differences <- vector("list",length(abcd))

for (i in 1:length(abcd)) {
            Differences[[i]] <- abs(UDRandomNum[[i]] - RandomNum[[i]])
}
```

**Explanation**

With the `UDRandomNum` list, try changing the `abcd` b and d columns into matrices that match the dimensions of `RandomNum`. And for the `Differences` list, R will automatically coerce the `TRUE` and `FALSE` results to 1 and 0 when you subtract the two matrices `UDRandomNum` and `RandomNum`.